# How to detect omitted input in matlab?

Tags: matlab

In the function `replace_me(v,a,b,c)` I want to replace `b`  with `b,b` if `c` is omitted.

My code is

```
if c == 0
    b = [b b]
end
```

When i run this code it gives me the next error

> Not enough input arguments.

Any help.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4):

Use `nargin` in the function body to detect the number of inputs. For your specific case:

```
function  replace_me(v,a,b,c)
        switch nargin
        case 4
                %// full case, do nothing
        case 3
                b = [b b];
        otherwise
                error('Invalid number of arguments');
        end;

        %// The rest of the code
end
```

Please note though that, after the `switch` statement, you should not reference anymore the argument `c`, because in the case of 3 arguments any reference of the omitted input will generate errors. This may seem confusing to the maintainers of your code (including yourself, after enough time). Maybe this way will make more sense, and be more robust:

```
function  replace_me(v,a,b,c)
        switch nargin
        case 4
                %// full case, do nothing
        case 3
                %// supply default value for c
                c = b; 
        otherwise
                error('Invalid number of arguments');
        end;

        %// The rest of the code
end
```

Of course, whether this is what you want or not is left to your evaluation (the posting doesn't offer too many details).

Answer (score 0):

At the begging of your function you might add

```
if nargin == 3
    c=b;
end
```